# Passing data to view container from another different view - Swift

Tags: swift, containers, segue

I need to pass some data from VC1 to the container of VC2, but the fact is that the container loads before than VC2 so I can't get the data just using parentViewController.data, so is there anything I can do to get the data from VC1 to the container of VC2 and loading it before VC2 does the ViewWillLoad function? I need to do it in swift.

Maybe there is some extra segue path like in tabBarController or NavigationController?

Comment: Lots of questions and answers on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: Not with containers mate, I have done a lot of research but with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution, i only had to get the parent data in function ViewWillAppear instead of ViewDidLoad. For some reason the creation order of parent and child views are:
1. VC2-container ViewDidLoad()
2. VC2 ViewDidLoad()
3. VC2-container ViewWillAppear()

So just by getting the data on ViewWillAppear will always get a not null atribute because it will have been set.